# Is it allright to remove the answered tag or I should not do that

Tags: discussion, support

One question of mine had an answer that I've accepted, but after couple of hours I have realised that it is not so complete is it sounded to me when I accepted it.

Comment: If you want to be nice about it, maybe add a comment pointing out the problem? If you have the solution, add it to their answer (either in comments or as an edit); if you don't, maybe the answerer can supply the missing information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion if you discover a major flaw in the answer, it is not only allowed, but even encouraged to remove the accept mark.

The reason is that you don't want people searching for the same problem and finding your post to be mislead by an answer that seems to work, but in the end doesn't. Even better to add a comment to explain what is the deficiency.

Of course as an answerer it is never nice to have your answer unaccepted, but in the end it is about the future readers.